# AWS: empty returned from lambda to frontend

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I have a simple application. The frontend is hosted in AWS Amplify. There is a Lamnda function that returns a string. And there is an API gateway in between.
I sucessfully tested the API gateway using curl. It returned the same string as the lambda reurned including the statusCode and the body. This indicates the Lambda nad the API gateway function fine.

As for the frontend code, I used the following to get the result of the Lambda.

```
  fetch(`${apiGatewayUrl}${resourcePath}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
      // Add any additional headers if required for authentication or other purposes
    },
  })
  .then(response => {
    alert (`response:: ${response.status}`)
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    
    alert('Raw response:', response);
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Process the data returned from the API
    console.log('API response:', data);
    alert('data:: ', JSON.stringify(data));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    alert (`Error: ${error}`);
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

the `${apiGatewayUrl}${resourcePath}` is set correctly. It is identical to the one I pass to curl.

For testing purpose, I set

```
 statusCode: 222,
```

in my Lamdba return.

When I execute my frontend code, the response.return is 200 as set in the API gateway.

The CORS is configured.
The method request, Integration request, integration response and method response is left at defaults.

What shall I do to make this work?

Comment: To test an API, I suggest you to use API testing tool like Postman to test the API, instead of doing it on your frontend. Also, can you explain more about what do you mean by an empty response? Do you mean the return has no body?

Comment: I might assume the problem is with CORS. Ensure that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is correctly set to allow your domain.

Comment: Yes, empty response has empty body, also the statusCode set in the lambda function is not populated to the frontend. I use curl for testing. It is OK, it returns what the lambda returns.